# Get data from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables

1. **UserPosts**(id, post, userfrom_id, userto_id, date)
2. **GroupPosts**(id, post, group_id, userfrom_id, userto_id, date)
3. **CommunityPosts**(id, post, community_id, user_id, date)

i want data from all theses 3 tables with related data like community *name* and *image* for community from **community** table (id, name, image)

similarly group's *name* and *image* from **groups** table and user, userfrom, userto's *name* and *image* from **users** table ordered by date

Now increasing the complexity a bit more **UserPost** has Many

1. **UserComments**(id, userpost_id, userid, commentm date) and
2. **UserVotes**(id, userpost_id,type, date)    ps:type is like/unlike

Similarly GroupPosts have GroupComments ang GroupVotes and CommunityPosts has CommunityVotes and CommunityComments. i want this data too

Now increasing the complexity a bit more it needs to be ordered by comments too(no votes, phew). What mean is if a post is 1 month old but has the a comment that was put up 5 min AGO then i needs to be listed above a post posted 1 day ago with all comments greater than 5min.

Also in the result i would like to know if the particular record is a community record or a group record or a user record

This is sort off like a facebook homepage that shows all your, your groups and friends activity. I an using PHP(cakephp), Mysql. Hope i have given all the necessary data

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: i can join community with user and post and likes and order by date that's it

Comment: well show what you have that works, work on the others and post the SQL you have that's not working as you want so that people can give you a hand.

Comment: Please make your question clearer. I don't see for example columns 'name' and 'image' in your tables.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your are looking for [`JOIN`](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php).

Comment: off course i know i have to use joins and unions but my problem is not that simple as a normal join as you can see. anyways thanks for the effort